# Redirect angular path but hold server data

Tags: angularjs

Sorry if this could be a newbie question.
So this frontend app has an interceptor.
For each request to server, the interceptor will be the first to manage the server response:

```
service.responseError = function (response) {

};
```

Now, if the server returns other status then 200, I want to redirect to another frontend path:

```
service.responseError = function (response) {
    if (response.status === 419){
        $location.path(handleError);
        return;
    }
    return response;
};
```

handleError is an angular controller. Can this controller come over the server response?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, doing this in interceptor:

```
$rootScope.interceptorData = response.data;
```

And then in controller injecting $rootScope and reading from it, solves it.